# How to change global variable from component in which it isn't declared

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I have Header component and there I defined hook:

```
 const [isUserLoggedIn, setUserLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  const userAutetication = () => {
    setUserLoggedIn(!isUserLoggedIn);
  }
```

`Header` contains component where I sent props in:

```
<div className='navbar'>
 <NavBar isUserLoggedIn={isUserLoggedIn} userAutetication={userAutetication} />
</div>
```

In `NavBar` component code looks like that:

```
function NavBar(props) {
    const { isUserLoggedIn, userAutetication } = props
    return (
        <div>
            {
                isUserLoggedIn ? (...):(...);
```

I want change these variable `isUserLoggedIn` in `Login` component. For example when I click Login button I want that `NavBar` to change. I don't know how to import `isUserLoggedIn` in `Login` component.
Can anybody help me how to change `NavBar` depending on `isUserLoggedIn`?

I tried the below code in `Header` component, but it didn't work well, I need to refresh page and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/Login").then((response) => {
      if (response.data.loggedIn === true) {
        setUserLoggedIn(true);
      }
      else
         setUserLoggedIn(false);
    });
  }, [isUserLoggedIn]);
```

I also tried to add `NavBar`'s prop in `Login` component:

```
const login = async () => {
        await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/Login", {
            email: formValues.email,
            password: formValues.password
        }).then((response) => {
            if (!response.data.auth) {
                setLoginStatus(false);
            } else {
                setLoginStatus(true);
               {NavBar(true)}
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: States are only valid for the Component they are in. I guess you're trying to make a Dynamic Navbar based on user login, you can use context for user auth. [REF](https://github.com/baxsm/blog-fullstack-nr/tree/main/client/src) to a dynamic navbar based on user auth. You can check Navbar, Login and Context for reference.

Comment: You might pass state as a prop from *parent* to *child* just like you did with your (*parent*) component `Header` you passed a prop `isUserLoggedIn` to (*child*) component `NavBar`, next: "*I don't know how to import `isUserLoggedIn` in component `Login`*" -> If `Login` component is child of your `Header` or `NavBar` you can just pass it as a prop. Further your question changes directions, it's unclear to me if you are trying achieve *conditional rendering* in your `NavBar` based on `isUserLoggedIn`? Elaborate your goal.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to achieve conditional rendering in my NavBar based on isUserLoggedIn

Comment: @baxsm you have right. Context solve my problems. I needed some time to figure it out, now I done what I want. Thank a lot!